# how to sign out in LinkedIn using authrequest using android?

Tags: android, oauth, integration, linkedin-api

i developed one app integrated with linkedIn..!
i do SignIn authentication in linkedIn using OAuth Service to post the Network Update..but now how to sign out (de-authenticate) to the LinkedIn automatically?

Thanks in adv..

Comment: I found One function to be logout "invalidateAccessToken(client.getAccessToken());" but its not woking...

Comment: i have try with following url https://www.linkedin.com/secure/login?session_full_logout=&trk=hb_signout  but it does not worked.

Comment: i also tried with https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/logout?oauth_token=<token-value> but it can't

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the official [blog](http://blog.linkedin.com/2010/04/29/linkedin-platform-oauth/)

> Token Invalidation

Now you can invalidate an OAuth token for your application.  Just send an OAuth signed GET request to:

> https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/invalidateToken

A 200 response indicates that the token was successfully invalidated.

However as per [this](http://developer.linkedin.com/comment/4726#comment-4726) :

> Third party applications do not have any way to log a user out from
>   LinkedIn - this is controlled by the website.  Invalidating the token
>   makes the user re-authorize the next time they try to use the
>   application, but once they have logged into LinkedIn their browser
>   will remain logged in until they log out via the website.

So In conclusion : as of this date of writing, Linked In does not give this support to 3rd Party Applications

Comment: i complete satisfied with ans.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question i have also tried to find solution and also talked to **Mr. Nabeel Siddiqui - Author of linkedin-j API**

and this was his reply when i asked if it's possible to sign out using linkedin-j api?

**Hi Mayur
There is a method LinkedInOAuthService#invalidateAccessToken that is supposed to invalidate your access token. Its not used much by the community so I am not sure if it works as expected or not. Do try it and let me know if there are problems.
Regards
Nabeel Mukhtar**

so in my activity i tried it using this way.

```
    final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
    LinkedInApiClient client;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACKURL);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
        startActivity(i);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Uri uri = intent.getData();

        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACKURL)) 
        {
            String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

            LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
            client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
            Connections con = client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser();

            //AFTER FETCHING THE DATA I HAVE DONE

             oAuthService.invalidateAccessToken(accessToken);
           //this is for sign out

        }
    }
```

Please, Try this way once and tell me if it solves your problem.

cause I have also donwloaded and seen the SourceCode for linkedin-j API and in 
**LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java**

they have given the function and that function also works if we write the same code in our file.
that is,

```
@Override
    public void invalidateAccessToken(LinkedInAccessToken accessToken) {
        if (accessToken == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("access token cannot be null.");
        }
        try {
            URL               url     = new URL(LinkedInApiUrls.LINKED_IN_OAUTH_INVALIDATE_TOKEN_URL);
            HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            final OAuthConsumer consumer = getOAuthConsumer();
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            consumer.sign(request);
            request.connect();

            if (request.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new LinkedInOAuthServiceException(convertStreamToString(request.getErrorStream()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new LinkedInOAuthServiceException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: nope..!! its not working with invalidateAccessToken() method.. user remains login after applying it..

Comment: ok..actually i didn't got enought time to test this..will do some more work arround and will let u know if i succeed.